# ffmpeg and streaming to youtube displaying logotype and webcamera

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, fedora, live-streaming, fedora-25

```
➜  tmp ffmpeg -version 
ffmpeg version 3.1.7 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 6.3.1 (GCC) 20161221 (Red Hat 6.3.1-1)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld' --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gcrypt --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcdio --enable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-nvenc --extra-cflags=-I/usr/include/nvenc --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-libmfx --enable-runtime-cpudetect
libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
```

**I'm streaming to youtube with the following settings**

```
ffmpeg \
-f x11grab -video_size 3840x2160 -framerate 30 -i :1.0 \
-f v4l2 -video_size 320x240 -framerate 30 -i /dev/video0 \
-f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -i logo.png -filter_complex \
"[0:v]scale=1920:-1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[bg]; \
 [1:v]scale=120:-1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[fg]; \
 [bg][fg]overlay=W-w-10:10[bg2]; \
 [bg2][3:v]overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10,format=yuv420p[out]" \
-map "[out]" -map 2:a -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast \
-maxrate 9000k -bufsize 12000k -c:a aac -b:a 160k -ar 44100 -b:a 128k \
-f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/TOKEN
```

[image]

I'm getting that huge black screen that cuts a lot of visible screen canvas. How do I get rid of it keeping webcamera preview on top and logo at the bottom?

#### This is what I see in console

https://gist.github.com/dmitry-saritasa/cc85ba6650d9bd50b28a61624711b96a

as you can see I only get 6-9fps while I expect 24+ (per settings?)

```
frame=  101 fps=6.4 q=23.0 size=    1669kB time=00:00:11.37 bitrate=1202.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=4 speed=0.718x    
frame=  105 fps=6.4 q=27.0 size=    1866kB time=00:00:12.09 bitrate=1263.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=4 speed=0.74x    
frame=  107 fps=6.4 q=28.0 size=    1871kB time=00:00:12.32 bitrate=1243.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=4 speed=0.732x    
frame=  111 fps=6.4 q=26.0 size=    1879kB time=00:00:12.79 bitrate=1203.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=4 speed=0.737x
```

---

## Questions

1. How to get rid of the top black area? So that I can screen share my full display?
2. How to increase fps?

Comment: Is part of your screen getting cut out at present or do you just have dead space at top?

Comment: Are you using Wayland?

Comment: Yes I'm using wayland. See the top right corner - this is my webcam reduced to scale=120. And all that dark area below the webcam box is weird. My screen starts navigation (darker black narrow line), but for some reason ffmpeg *or something else shifts the canvas down. My screen is 4K screen 3840x2160